# MySQL query to select nearest time from 12hrs time format

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I want to get nearest time with comparing specific time passed to it  I wrote mysql query for it but it is not working as per expectation below is my query with different case.please suggest me solution

Table:

```
id  date        time
1   2018-02-06  09:00 pm
2   2018-02-05  09:30 pm
3   2018-02-06  09:00 am
4   2018-02-07  10:00 am
```

Test case 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `date` = '2018-02-06'
AND `time` >= '08:16 am'
ORDER BY `time` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Expected output:

```
id  date        time
3   2018-02-06  09:00 am
```

Test case 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `date` = '2018-02-06'
AND `time` >= '08:16 pm'
ORDER BY `time` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Expected output:

```
id  date        time
1   2018-02-06  09:00 pm
```

Comment: Store times as `time` to begin with.

Comment: `TIME` datatype in MySQL cannot store values similar to `09:30 pm`. So show CREATE TABLE of source table...

Answer (score 1):

Comparing date and time portion separately is a pain in the bottom. I would suggest storing date and time as a single `datetime` column. Having  said that, you can always convert strings to datetime using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```sql
select *
from t
where str_to_date(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') >= '2018-02-06 08:16' -- <- proper date
order by str_to_date(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
limit 1
```

Comment: Salman A but I need solution based on separated ate time column and time column structure is varchar because I have to store am/pm  like 09:00 am, 07:00 pm

Comment: @msp someone deleted my (valid) comment. Anyway, the above solution still works with your design. You just need to specify `2018-02-06 08:16` instead of two separate `2018-02-06` and `08:16 pm`